# Drag and drop not working in document library for files taken from mobile storage

Tags: sharepoint-online

I can drag images through desktop but when I connect mobile to PC, I'm not able to drag and drop through Mobile Storage.

Does anybody have any idea about external storage drag and drop support by Office 365 SharePoint?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No but while dragging image not getting drag & drop blue ribbon.